# Clock and data vs rx and tx communication

Tags: pic, serial, communication, clock, data

I'm working on a project in which I have to make two pic10f200 microcontrollers communicate via serial communication lines. I know that with Arduino you interconnect the two board's rx and tx lines, but I have no experience with the Picaxe's clock and data pins.

What are the differences between these to communication methods and how could I acheive a master-slave configuration with the pic?

Thanks!

Comment: Try reading the data sheet.

Comment: I looked but I couldn't find anything about master-slave communication...

Comment: Your search is too specific. If a device responds to a command on it's RX pin (or other input) and responds on the TX pin (or other pin ) it is the slave but we may not call it a slave. examples are anything that responds only when it receives input from the mcu (ADC, DAC, intelligent LED drivers, temperature sensors ..etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pic10f200 has only 0.375 KB of program memory, 16 BYTES of RAM and no built in communication modules. This is not enough memory to build any kind of software based communication scheme that you might be happy with or possibly at all. You need to select another part if you want communication.

Look at I2C, UART and SPI communication. Select a part with the communication module that suits you needs. Try using the [Microchip MAPS tool](http://www.microchip.com/maps/microcontroller.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try to find a something better then.

Comment: I have bit banged serial in that amount of memory using assembler, it was only half duplex. But how much useful space is left is hard to recall.